# Python script to run series of commands and run an exectuable file

Tags: python, scripting, automated-tests

I am currently trying to write a Python script that I will execute on my development board. Basically what I am trying to do, is go through the rootfile system (which is just like your home directory, etc. on your machine) and get to a directory where my graphic tutorials live (there tutorials are executable files that run a 3D rendered graphic onto the board until I kill it by pressing Ctrl + C).

So the graphics tests live in a directory called /vdk/tutorials/ and then to execute a tutorial I run the command "./tutorial1_es2gears"

I am trying to automate this process through a python script that gets to that directory and executes that tutorial for a certain period of time. My situation is that I cannot figure out how to do this. I tried subprocesses, but that doesn't seem to allow me to run a executable file (or I do not know how to)

Please let me know if you have any tips

Comment: add what you have tried

Answer (score 0):

```
import subprocess
import os
print os.getcwd()
p = subprocess.Popen("./tutorial1_es2gears")
p.communicate()
```

or even more simply

```
os.system("./tutorial1_es2gears")
```

thats assuming you want to block until you finish with that other program